# Pandas Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm trying to create a COVID-19 map of the United States with plotly/choropleth, and I need to convert the various ways states are listed into the 2-digit state codes.  Some are just the full name, and that I have solved by mapping a dictionary of the codes to it.  But others are of the format "County or City, CA".

What I am trying to do is say if the value in "Province/State" column contains a comma, create a new column that takes the last 2 characters (to return the state code), otherwise map the dictionary (ie: {California:CA}).

```
codes = pd.read_csv('country_codes.csv')
codes = dict(zip(codes.Full, codes.Abbv))

if covid['Province/State'].str.contains(','):
    covid['State'] = covid['Province/State'].str[-2:]
else:
    covid['State'] = covid['Province/State'].map(codes)
```

I get the following error with the if statement:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

But if I run just this: `covid['Province/State'].str.contains(',')`
it works and is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a boolean series in a conditional as you would any Python variable. Instead, you can use it as a mask to select and insert values in the dataframe:

```py
# Create boolean mask
has_comma = covid["Province/State"].str.contains(",")  # a boolean series

# Create column with default value of empty string
covid["State"] = ""

# Change "State" values where condition is true
covid.loc[has_comma, "State"] = covid["Province/State"].str[-2:]

# Change "State" values where condition is false
covid.loc[~has_comma, "State"] = covid["Province/State"].map(codes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `covid['Province/State'].str.contains(',')` returns a boolean series, which will raise an exception if you try to evaluate its truthiness, as you've seen.

Try doing this:

```
has_comma = covid['Province/State'].str.contains(',')
covid.loc[has_comma, 'State'] = covid['Province/State'].str[-2:]
covid.loc[~has_comma, 'State'] = covid['Province/State'].map(codes)
```